# Can two different rules be applied at the same step in Type 0 Grammar

Tags: context-free-grammar

As a rule in CFG, we have the liberty of applying any rule for the string S anywhere in the derivation. We can also apply different rule in one step. For example, consider the string S->0S1S and say for example that we have two rules, S->0 and S->1. Then in CFG we can apply both of these & can get 0011 as a result. 
My question is that is this liberty allowed in Type 0 Grammar also? I am stuck at this point in one of the problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of the type of the grammar, the derivation rules are the same.  So, the answer to your question is yes, **but**...

You should not view the derivation in your example as one step, rather it consists of two steps where you first replace one $S$ and then in the *next* step the other $S$.

For example, if some of your rules are $Ax \rightarrow y$ and $xB \rightarrow z$, then from $AxB$ you can derive $yB$ (by the first rule) *or* $Az$ (by the second).  But you can **not** use both rules at once and derive $yz$ (where you would have "used" $x$ twice).